# How to make the volume change more gradually?

Tags: sound, thinkpad, volume-control

So I'm currently using Ubuntu 13.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad R61i laptop and the problem I have is that the actual sound volume doesn't grow linearly with the change of the volume slider position: in the range from 0% to 75% it grows very slowly, but in the range from 75% to 100% does so very rapidly - so that a small change of the slider's position corresponds to an unproportionally large change in volume.

What might be the case and how can I fix it? Used to work well on Ubuntu 11.*

Comment: @Braiam *So I'm currently using Ubuntu 13.04*...

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 has reached end of life. You should upgrade to 13.10 or 14.04 LTS (or downgrade to 12.04 LTS).

Comment: @ToDo is was not on aug 2, 2013 :)

Comment: This question may be relevant for recent Ubuntu releases too.

Answer (score 0):

If the volume slider seems off, you may try adjusting the volume in alsamixer first (should be set to middle for volume I believe).

In terminal type

```
alsamixer
```

and then use your arrow keys to adjust the volume that way, check to be sure your volume slider isn't already all the way at the top, throwing things off.  I try to get mine to be around even with my volume slider and then adjust volume a few times to make sure everything works correctly.